# How to move an unordered list to a new part on a page in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, list, move

Here's the story. I've got an unordered list inside a div on my page.

The code:

```
<div id="move-me">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The above code is positioned on the left of the page, now what I want to do is, destroy the div and ul elements and be only left with the links. Then finally append these links to a sidebar list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy!

```
$("#move-me").remove().find('a').appendTo("#somewhere-else");
```

[An example.](http://jsbin.com/okobi)

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the links from the LI tags then add to the sidebar then remove the unordered list.  Something like this should work:

$('#move-me > a').appendTo('#sidebar');
$('#move-me').remove();